# how to make a file that looks like this "https://www.facebook.com/messages/100005408564" with no .php or .txt or anything

Tags: php, facebook

I dont really know how to ask this question, but i just see this everywhere and i don't know how it's done.
https://www.facebook.com/messages/100006335564
this id in the end, is it a file or what is it ? and how can i do something like that?

this is my question, i'll just post code so it accepts the question coz its too short. so dont care about the code

```
 CREATE TABLE Classes(
ClassID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
CollegeID INT NOT NULL,
ClassName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ClassType VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ClassID)
 );

CREATE TABLE College(
CollegeID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
UniversityName TEXT NOT NULL,
CollegeName TEXT NOT NULL,
Username varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
img varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
timeval TIME
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done in a `.htaccess` file on the server, using `mod_rewrite`.  This answer should clear things up:

[PHP .htaccess mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833654/php-htaccess-mod-rewrite)
EDIT:
This one might make a little more sense:
[Mod_Rewrite .Htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889136/mod-rewrite-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable mod_rewrite on your apache and also configure your public directory to allowOverride ALL instead of none
Then you place .htaccess in your document public folder with rules to route none files or directory found to a common script usually index.php
In your index.php you read the query string and process or route the information based on the values of your query string.